# What is amd64.tar.xz?

Tags: 12.04

I tried Ubuntu 13.10 yesterday and had some really bad experiences, such as Ubuntu not coming back from sleep mode. Now I have downloaded the 12.04.1 version and started the installer. Now the installer is downloading a file called amd64.tar.xz which is taking about *six hours* to complete. What is that?

My computer has the following specs: AMD Turion X2 Ultra Dual-Core CPU ZM-80, 
 ATI Mobility Radeon HD 8650 4BG RAM  DDR3.

I downloaded the 32-bit version, since I want a smooth and fast OS, not some junk. Why is the installer downloading that file? Will it install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on my PC?

[image: Screenshot of download progress bar]

[image: Screenshot of Wubi folder]

As a separate question, why is it taking so long for Ubuntu to boot, and why, after selecting which OS to boot, do I always have to choose between Ubuntu and Advanced options for Ubuntu?

Comment: What method did you use to install 12.04 ? Did you look at the ISO file and LiveUSB solution, which could be more handy for you ?

Comment: Hello. I extracted iso and started installer like simple exe instalation. I will add photos to help. In the question

Comment: I tried 13.10 64bit. Its an disaster. My Win7 is running smootly.

Comment: @MrVaykadji That is not true. Ubuntu 32-bit is PAE enabled by default and will use more than 3GB of RAM easily.

Comment: Why is ubuntu so complicated. Damm. next next next yes GG.

Comment: @DjolexInc you are doing it wrong, you should not use WUBI because it is deprecated. Go for the full installation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem :

Download amd64.tar.x from this [Link](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/ubuntu-12.04.1-wubi-amd64.tar.xz.506081252-0.html)

Save it on a path and remember this path .

Now open cmd and add this command :

```
wubi.exe --dimagepath=(path of the file example d:\name.amd64.tar.x)
```

Now it will extract it instead of downloading it .

This is image file for Ubuntu . size approx 500MB